# join multiple result to one result in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Driverperformance] 
      @Ecode NVARCHAR(50), 
      @startdate DATETIME, 
      @enddate DATETIME 
AS  

      BEGIN 
      DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate + ' 00:01:00.000', 120); 
      DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate + ' 23:23:59.000', 120) ; 

      SELECT 
          e.ecode,   
          Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date,   
          e.ename, 
          Count(q.ecode) cntEcode   
     FROM employeemaster_tbl e JOIN transaction_tbl q ON e.ecode = q.ecode 
     WHERE  
          q.ecode = @Ecode     
          AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + ''   
          AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
     GROUP BY 
          e.ecode,  
          e.ename,   
          Cast(q.dtime AS DATE)  

     SELECT 
          e.ecode, 
          Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date, 
          e.ename, 
          Count(q.delecode)     DelEcode 
     FROM employeemaster_tbl e JOIN transaction_tbl q ON e.ecode = q.delecode  
     WHERE 
          q.delecode = @Ecode 
          AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + '' 
          AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
     GROUP BY 
          e.ecode, 
          e.ename,   
          Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) 
     ORDER  BY Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) 
  END
```

I am getting first result:

```
Ecode   Date         Ename    CntEcode  
E003    2013-05-05   Raheem    4                    
E003    2013-05-28   Raheem    1
```

Second result:

```
Ecode   Date         Ename    CntEcode  
E003    2013-05-05   Raheem    3         
E003    2013-05-27   Raheem    7           
E003    2013-05-28   Raheem    1
```

But I want to get out put in one result like this:

```
Ecode   Date         Ename    CntEcode   DelEcode
E003    2013-05-05   Raheem    4            3
E003    2013-05-27   Raheem    0            7
E003    2013-05-28   Raheem    1            1
```

How can I achieve this? If any one know please help me to find out.

Comment: inner join the results and tweek query accordingly

Comment: means removing order by and other changes to run the query

Comment: where i have to add inner join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like dates can be missing from either table so a `FULL JOIN` would appear to be more appropriate and use `ISNULL` to get `0` when the counts for that day are null

Try:

```
; WITH cnt AS
(
SELECT 
      e.ecode,   
      Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date,   
      e.ename, 
      Count(q.ecode) cntEcode   
 FROM employeemaster_tbl e JOIN transaction_tbl q ON e.ecode = q.ecode 
 WHERE  
      q.ecode = @Ecode     
      AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + ''   
      AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
 GROUP BY 
      e.ecode,  
      e.ename,   
      Cast(q.dtime AS DATE)  
), 
del AS
(
 SELECT 
      e.ecode, 
      Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date, 
      e.ename, 
      Count(q.delecode)     DelEcode 
 FROM employeemaster_tbl e JOIN transaction_tbl q ON e.ecode = q.delecode  
 WHERE 
      q.delecode = @Ecode 
      AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + '' 
      AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
 GROUP BY 
      e.ecode, 
      e.ename,   
      Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) 
)

SELECT ISNULL(del.ecode, ctn.ecode) ecode
       , ISNULL(del.[Date], cnt.[Date]) [Date]
       , ISNULL(del.ename, cnt.ename) ename
       , ISNULL(cnt.cntEcode, 0) CntEcode
       , ISNULL(del.cntEcode, 0) AS DelEcode
FROM cnt
FULL JOIN del ON del.ecode = cnt.ecode
             AND del.[Date] = cnt.[Date]
             AND del.Ename = cnt.Ename
```

Comment: sir i will check and let you know

Comment: Perferct..thanks a lot sir...i shall be very thank full to you

Comment: Cool. So you managed to get multiple people write the code for you, by asking multiple questions. Ingenious of you to take the answer to one question and build your next question around it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use what T I posted in the first part:

```
WITH firstResult AS
(
SELECT 
      e.ecode,   
      Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS DateAdded,   
      e.ename, 
      Count(q.ecode) cntEcode   
 FROM employeemaster_tbl e JOIN transaction_tbl q ON e.ecode = q.ecode 
 WHERE  
      q.ecode = @Ecode     
      AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + ''   
      AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
 GROUP BY 
      e.ecode,  
      e.ename,   
      Cast(q.dtime AS DATE)  
), 
secondResult AS
(
 SELECT 
      e.ecode, 
      Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS DateAdded, 
      e.ename, 
      Count(q.delecode) as DelEcode 
 FROM employeemaster_tbl e JOIN transaction_tbl q ON e.ecode = q.delecode  
 WHERE 
      q.delecode = @Ecode 
      AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + '' 
      AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
 GROUP BY 
      e.ecode, 
      e.ename,   
      Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) 
)
```

But use ISNULL also for Ecode, DateAdded and EName since we have a full join and also the values in secondResult table can be null:

```
select ISNULL(firstResult.Ecode,secondResult.Ecode) as Ecode,ISNULL(firstResult.DateAdded,secondResult.DateAdded) as DateAdded,  
    ISNULL(firstResult.Ename,secondResult.Ename) as Ename, ISNULL(firstResult.EntEcode,0) as Ecode, ISNULL(secondResult.DelEcode,0) as DelEcode
    from
    firstResult full outer join secondResult on firstResult.Ecode = secondResult.Ecode and firstResult.DateAdded = secondResult.DateAdded
    order by DateAdded
```

Comment: You're welcome! At the time of posting, the first answer was not complete, but now it is fine.